# How do wire screw handles work?

Tags: screws

[image: screw and handle]

I acquired a chest of drawers and one of the handles of the drawers came out and I was surprised to see that they were twisted wires. Looking on the other side there are screws. So neither the wires nor the screws go the full way through the wood. It seems that the screws tighten the wires and they stay in there with friction.

Questions:

- Does this type of attachment have a name?
- How does this attachment work?
- How does one repair this when it comes loose? (Just the obvious of filling the hole with sawdust/glue combo and drilling it out?)

Edits:

- Yes, all the handles look like this and were assembled in the same way so it looks like it was factory original and intentional.
- There is no damage or marking on the inside of the drawers to suggest that there was ever a butterflied wire in there.

Comment: `Does this type of attachment have a name?` ... probably `DIY fix`

Comment: This looks like a fix after the handle broke. What do the other handles on the chest of drawers look like?

Comment: @JACK - All the handles were attached identical to this. It looks like it was the original way that it was done.

Comment: Check out my edited answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have similar furniture at home. It was classed as 'imported Mexican antique', though the furniture itself is 'new' not antique. It is made of recycled 100-year-old wood, complete with rustically-charming [& dead] woodworm holes, dings, dents & chips; and rusty handles.
The wires on mine go right through then bend outwards on the inside to hold it firm. They look flimsy but have lasted 25 years with no fails yet.

There are several 'double' handles just like yours but they're harder to photograph, so here's one I could reach more easily.

[image] [image]

As the wire ends are somewhat rounded, I can only guess that someone in the past has clipped yours short, or that they were only ever glued in place. Those self-tapping screws are someone else's earlier attempt at a repair.

To keep the 'rustic charm' I think you have to keep the wire.
I'd be tempted towards an epoxy resin glue [a two pack, Araldite is the well-known UK product]; push the wires back into place & once hardened should be fairly tough. Bin the screws, they're ugly even on the inside of a drawer. Those decorative cover-plates, btw, are just free to spin… again 'rustic charm'.

Comment: Thank you @Tetsujin. This is super valuable info. I'm in Arizona so highly likely my piece was made in Mexico with similar style to yours. That handle you show is also on mine on the single top drawers. None of mine have the butterflied wire you showed but that looks like the perfect way to fix it.

Comment: See my edited answer, you nailed it. :-)

Comment: @JACK - nice find. By strange coincidence, I also have a chest of drawers with handles very similar to your original example;)

Comment: I like how the end of the wire is bent back then nailed into the inside of the drawer to hold in place. Very simple and very clever design.

Answer (score 6):

What you've got is a broken handle that someone tried to fix the best they could. Originally the handle probably looked very similar to the one shown below from Ebay. The pieces the screws go into probably snapped or became stripped so they were replaced with the wire.

[image]

EDIT:  Now I stand corrected about this. While I do have a dresser with the above handles, my wife had bought a little four drawer chest that I didn't even know about and put it in her office. Here are a few pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

So @Tetsujin nailed it.

Comment: Your theory's half right, I would guess; but there's no reason the wire isn't the original. I have very similar wired handles at home.

Comment: JACK - thanks for the idea - much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for editing and confirming this JACK!